# Is there a way to remove the site nav from a single page in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am creating a landing page where I do not want any navigation and it is injecting the site header HTML. Is there a way to make a landing page without any navigation in BigCommerce? I am using the Corner Stone them.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to duplicate the `templates/layout/base.html` file, remove the header from there, then create a new custom template in `templates/custom/page/` which then references the new layout that doesn't include the header.

You can then assign your page to that new template.